# React Router renders parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a `MainPage` component which renders `LoginPage` component. In `LoginPage` there is `LoginForm` which can route to `SignUpPage`. When I route to `SingUpPage` on top of it `LoginPage` rendered again how can I fix this?

**MainPage.js**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className={'main-container'}>
            <LoginPage />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**LoginPage.js**

```
render() {
    let { loginReducer } = this.props;
    //console.log('Login Reducer', loginReducer);

    return(
        <div className={'login-page-container'}>
            <LoginForm />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**LoginForm.js**

```
...form inputs, buttons etc
<Route path='/signup' component={SignUpPage} />
<Route path='/forgot-password' component={ForgotPassword} />
```

In `LoginForm` I can route to `SignUpPage` but on top of it there is again `LoginForm`. How can I prevent it?

**SignUpPage**

```
return(
        <div className={'container'}>
            <SignUpForm />
        </div>
    );
```

**SignUpForm**

```
... text inputs, buttons etc
<Route path='/login' exact component={LoginPage} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your **AppRouter** the parent of your **MainPage**. Do all the routing stuff from this **AppRouter** class.

In your **AppRouter**, have the following routes

```
<Route path='/' exact component={LoginPage} /> // OR MainPage
<Route path='/login' exact component={LoginPage} />
<Route path='/signup' exact component={SignUpPage} />
<Route path='/forgot-password' exact component={ForgotPassword} />
```

Do not define any other `Route` other than this component.

Comment: Hi Burak, can you provide a code part of it? I couldn't imagine how to do it.